# Android: How to move entire layout up except for the background image

Tags: android, xml

When the soft keyboard shows up, I only want the Views inside the most outer layout to be pushed up.  The reason is because the most outer layout has a background which gets squished when the keyboard shows up. I want the background to be unaffected.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when developing a chat app. What worked for me was setting the background on the window and not in the layout. Like this:

```
 getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_hd);
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I'm making a chat app.  Worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the following:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in the `<activity../>` tag in `AndroidManifest`?

This should adjust the size of your layout in this activity when the keyboard is displayed.

There are plenty of more implementations you can use to handle different states RE the documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Same result. Everything got pushed up. The background image gets scaled.  I want the background image unchanged.